# .yml does not install packages from .requirements.txt in the dedicated environment

Tags: python, azure-devops, continuous-integration

I have the following which should install packages from `requirements.txt` in the environment `Env_Name` which has just been created

```
- script: |
    python -m venv Env_Name
    cd Env_Name
    .\scripts\Activate
  displayName: 'Create & Activate Env_Name '

- script: |
    python -m pip install --upgrade pip
  displayName: 'Install dependencies'

- script: |
    pip install wheel
  displayName: 'Wheel install' 

- script: |
    pip install python_ldap-3.4.0-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl
  displayName: 'Install ldap from wheel' 

- script: |
    type requirements.txt
  displayName: 'display the content of the requirements file'

- script: |
    pip install -r requirements.txt -v
  displayName: 'packages installation'

- script: |
    pip list
  displayName: 'Display packages'

- script: |
    python setup.py sdist
  displayName: 'Artifact creation'

- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    targetFolder: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'My_App'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

---

display packages does show that packages have been installed :

```
pip list
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
"C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe" /D /E:ON /V:OFF /S /C "CALL "D:\a\_temp\f53d2436-67e2-4d6f-bf00-e90e1dfcb18c.cmd""
Package              Version
-------------------- ------------
asgiref              3.7.2
beautifulsoup4       4.12.2
certifi              2023.7.22
cffi                 1.15.1
charset-normalizer   3.2.0
contourpy            1.1.1
cryptography         41.0.3
cx_Oracle            8.3.0
cycler               0.11.0
Django               4.2.5
django-adminlte3     0.1.6
django-auth-ldap     4.6.0
django-mssql-backend 2.8.1
et-xmlfile           1.1.0
fonttools            4.42.1
idna                 3.4
joblib               1.3.2
kiwisolver           1.4.5
lxml                 4.9.3
```

but looking into the env folder i can only see in site-packages :

[image]

as we can see, we there is no packages from requirements.txt. So the question is :

Where are all these packages installed ? Is there a script which can be used to show the path of the folder where they are ?

How do I get them installed in `Env_Name` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where are all these packages installed ? Is there a script which can be used to show the path of the folder where they are ?

In Azure DevOps, the python packages will be installed to the default system path.

We can use the following script to get the system path:

```
python -m site
```

Check the **sys.path**  value and find the **site-packages** path.

Or you can use the command to get the target package installed path:

```
pip show packagename
```

For example:

[image]

> How do I get them installed in Env_Name ?

To install the packages in the Env_Name, you can add the argument:`--target="Env_Name/lib/site-packages"`

Here is an example:

```
- script: |
    python -m venv Env_Name
    cd Env_Name
    .\scripts\Activate
  displayName: 'Create & Activate Env_Name '

- script: |
    python -m pip install --upgrade pip
  displayName: 'Install dependencies'

- script: |
    pip install wheel
  displayName: 'Wheel install' 

- script: |
    pip install python_ldap-3.4.0-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl
  displayName: 'Install ldap from wheel' 

- script: |
    type requirements.txt
  displayName: 'display the content of the requirements file'

- script: |
    pip install -r requirements.txt -v --target="Env_Name/lib/site-packages"
  displayName: 'packages installation'

....
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Is it the same than doing : `Env_Name\scripts\pip install -r requirements.txt -v`

This way seems to install requirements.txt seems to work, I can see all packages installed in `site-packages` but when i go in windows `cmd` to see all the packages installed it seems that : 

`django-adminlte3==0.1.6`
`django-auth-ldap==4.6.0`
`django-mssql-backend==2.8.1`
`mssql-django==1.4`

Are misssing, all other packages are being installed well and in the raw log there is no failure for the installation of these packages..
Any Idea ?

Comment: `Successfully installed Django-4.2.5 Pillow-10.0.1 asgiref-3.7.2 beautifulsoup4-4.12.2 certifi-2023.7.22 cffi-1.15.1 charset-normalizer-3.2.0 contourpy-1.1.1 cryptography-41.0.3 cx-Oracle-8.3.0 cycler-0.11.0 django-adminlte3-0.1.6 django-auth-ldap-4.6.0 django-mssql-backend-2.8.1 et-xmlfile-1.1.0 fonttools-4.42.1 idna-3.4 joblib-1.3.2 kiwisolver-1.4.5 lxml-4.9.3 matplotlib-3.8.0 mssql-django-1.4 numpy-1.26.0 openpyxl-3.1.2 oracledb-1.4.1 packaging-23.1 pandas-2.1.0 pandas-datareader-0.10.0 patsy-0.5.3 pycparser-2.21 pyodbc-5.1.0 pyparsing-3.1.1 python-dateutil-2.8.2
`

Comment: @TourEiffel  Yes. The command you use has the same feature as my command in the answer.  Test the command and it can install all packages. Can you try to add the argument: `--force-reinstall` in the pip install command to  force removing the existing packages and then installing the current versions.

Comment: like this ? `Env_Name\scripts\pip install -r requirements.txt -v --force-reinstall`

Comment: @TourEiffel Yes, your format is correct. If you are using self-hosted agent, my guess is that it may be because of the cache issue. We can try to force re-install the packages.  And you need to make sure the requirements.txt file path is correct.

Comment: I made sure that requirements.txt has correct path using `type requirements.txt` which display the content of the file. So I think this is not a path issue. I will force reinstall and will keep you updated on this behaviour.

Comment: @TourEiffel oh YES. I checked the yaml again. The path should be correct. You can try to force re-installing the packages and check if it can work for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256925/discussion-between-toureiffel-and-kevin-lu-msft).

Comment: @TourEiffel I test to use the similar requirement.txt and the YAML sample to install python packages. And all packages can be found in the env_name folder. and when running the command:  `env_name\scripts\pip list -v` , it will show all required packages. Can you try to upload the 'env_name' folder to build artifacts and check if you can see all packages?

Answer (score 1):

Each `script` block is often executed in a separate shell and resets the environment between scripts; install the `requirements.txt` in the same `script` block as the one where you create and activate the environment.

Comment: Might be worth spelling out that "separately" in this case means "in a separate shell", such that changing the state of one shell doesn't change the state of others.